# PhpStorm does not show Missing parameter's type declaration warning

Tags: php, phpstorm, inspection

PhpStorm (version 2022.3.1) simply does not show "Missing parameter's type declaration warning".

In this piece of code I intentionally leave `$name` parameter in `getId()` method without type declaration and expect PhpStorm to highlight it:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class TestClass
{
    private int $id = 1;

    public function getId($name): int
    {
        return $name === 'Citibank' ? 0 : $this->id;
    }
}
```

But nothing happens.

I've checked `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> PHP -> Type compatibility` - the checkbox is checked, Scope - 'In All Scopes', Severity - 'Warning'.

I've also went through all the steps in `File -> Repair IDE`.

But still I get only one Weak Warning: 'Unused element: TestClass'.

Any ideas why is this happening? I know it looks more like a bug report, but I there's still a chance that it is a configuration problem or someone has encountered it before.

P.S. If anyone's willing to check my settings, here's exported file: [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yf_FK6mp197v0HbMh30cNbyqLrjWKIVV/view?usp=share_link).

Comment: I can reproduce this, it looks like a bug to me. I can get it to report a missing return type, but not about the parameter type.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58388/Inspection-Missing-parameters-type-declaration-not-working-without-the-PHPDoc-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the referenced version (2022.3.1) this is still tied to the existence of a DocBlock annotation. Only if the DocBlock exists will this be checked. There is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58388/Inspection-Missing-parameters-type-declaration-not-working-without-the-PHPDoc-block) reporting this.